# Which lib do I import to use create_shortcut() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

I am trying to use the create_shortcut() function in a post-installation script in Python 3.2, per http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html#the-postinstallation-script . Every time I try to run the function, i get the following:

```
NameError: name 'create_shortcut' is not defined
```

I feel like I am missing an import, but I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on how to get this working.

EDIT
I should have specified earlier my final goal and my environment. I am building an .msi running the following:
    python setup.py bdist_msi --initial-target-dir="C:\path\to\install" --install-script="install.py"
The install.py file lives in the same directory as my setup.py.

The final goal is to have a .msi file that installs the application in the specified directory and creates a Start Menu item in a specified location. It would be a nice to have if the installer allows the user to select to create the Start Menu shortcut or a desktop shortcut.

Comment: The docs just say it's exposed in the context where the post-install script is run. I can't find any reference to an import for it, though I bet you can dig it out somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Postinstallation script is to run in the native Windows installation routine.

Fuctions `get_special_folder_path`, `directory_created`, `directory_created` and `create_shortcut` are not pythonic: for example, they cannot be called as keyword-argument pairs - only positionally. The functions are defined at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PC/bdist_wininst/install.c

A routine for the shorcut creation acts as a wrapper around system interface [`IShellLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx) ( "lives" in shell32.dll ) and starts at line 504:

```
static PyObject *CreateShortcut(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{...
```

and then is linked at line 643:

```
PyMethodDef meth[] = {
    {"create_shortcut", CreateShortcut, METH_VARARGS, NULL},
    {"get_special_folder_path", GetSpecialFolderPath, METH_VARARGS, NULL},
  ...
};
```

In your local installation the above C code is already compiled in the executables:

```
C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-6.0.exe
C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-7.1.exe
C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-8.0.exe
C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-9.0.exe
C:\Python26\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-9.0-amd64.exe
```

So, answer: There is no python lib to import the function create_shortcut(), it is available as-is only inside a Windows postinstallation script.

If you want to support both automatic and manual postinstall scenarios, look at the pywin32 workaround:

https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/pywin32_postinstall.py line 80

```
try:
    create_shortcut
except NameError:
    # Create a function with the same signature as create_shortcut provided
    # by bdist_wininst
    def create_shortcut(path, description, filename,
                        arguments="", workdir="", iconpath="", iconindex=0):
        import pythoncom
        from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

        ilink = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_ShellLink, None,
                                           pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                           shell.IID_IShellLink)
        ilink.SetPath(path)
        ilink.SetDescription(description)
        if arguments:
            ilink.SetArguments(arguments)
        if workdir:
            ilink.SetWorkingDirectory(workdir)
        if iconpath or iconindex:
            ilink.SetIconLocation(iconpath, iconindex)
        # now save it.
        ipf = ilink.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)
        ipf.Save(filename, 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

As the documentation says:

> Starting with Python 2.3, **a postinstallation script can be specified with the --install-script option**. The basename of the script must be specified, and **the script filename must also be listed in the scripts argument to the setup function**.

These are windows only options, you need to use it when you build a executable installer of your module. Try:

```
python setup.py bdist_wininst --help
python setup.py bdist_wininst --install-script postinst.py --pre-install-script preinst.py
```

This file needs to go in the "script" section of your setup.py file.

> Some functions especially useful in this context are **available as additional built-in functions** in the installation script.

This means you don't have to import any module.

Comment: “This file needs to go in the "script" section of your setup.py file”  What script section?

Comment: This does not answer the question